# How to enable fulfillment webhook for Intent using java client in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have written below code to set intent using java code. Its woorking fine. Now I want to enable webhook fulfillment for this intent however I am not able to find any method for that. Can someone help me with it.

```
Intent intent =
          Intent.newBuilder()
              .setDisplayName(displayName)
              .addMessages(message)
              .addAllTrainingPhrases(trainingPhrases)
              .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable the webhook fulfillment in the intent, you can add [setWebhookState(int value)](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-dialogflow/latest/com/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2/Intent.Builder.html#setWebhookState-com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.WebhookState-) and **set the value to 1**. See [reference](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-dialogflow/latest/com/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2/Intent.WebhookState.html#WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED) for int values of enable webhook state.

> public static final Intent.WebhookState WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED
> Webhook is enabled in the agent and in the intent.
>
> - WEBHOOK_STATE_ENABLED = 1;

You code will look something like this:

```
Intent intent =
          Intent.newBuilder()
              .setDisplayName(displayName)
              .addMessages(message)
              .addAllTrainingPhrases(trainingPhrases)
              .setWebhookState(value) // value = 1
              .build();
```